# Why occur exception java.lang.IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, android-camera

My code setting `MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;`

```
 mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.unlock();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
try {
            if (Audio_source > -1)
                mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Audio_source);
            else
                mMediaRecorder
                        .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
            if (Video_source > -1)
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(Video_source);
            else
                mMediaRecorder
                        .setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            if (Video_outputformat > -1)
                mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Video_outputformat);
            else
                mMediaRecorder
                        .setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

            if (Video_encorder > -1)
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(Video_encorder);
            else
                mMediaRecorder
                        .setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            if (Video_framerate > -1) {
                mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(Video_framerate);
            }

            // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
            mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                        .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            E022.saveErrorLog(e.getMessage(), context);
        }
```

Target values of :

```
Audio_source = -1, Video_source = -1, Video_outputformat = -1,
            Video_encorder = -1, Video_framerate = -1
```

Ex:

```
03-12 14:54:12.937: W/System.err(11577): java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-12 14:54:12.938: W/System.err(11577):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
03-12 14:54:12.940: W/System.err(11577):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setProfile(MediaRecorder.java:366)
03-12 14:54:12.942: W/System.err(11577):    at jp.osaka.ECAMERA.prepareVideoRecorder(ECAMERA.java:1300)
03-12 14:54:12.945: W/System.err(11577):    at jp.osaka.ECAMERA.access$16(ECAMERA.java:1259)
03-12 14:54:12.947: W/System.err(11577):    at jp.osaka.ECAMERA$6.onClick(ECAMERA.java:347)
03-12 14:54:12.948: W/System.err(11577):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
03-12 14:54:12.950: W/System.err(11577):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
03-12 14:54:12.952: W/System.err(11577):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-12 14:54:12.954: W/System.err(11577):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 14:54:12.956: W/System.err(11577):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 14:54:12.957: W/System.err(11577):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4503)
03-12 14:54:12.958: W/System.err(11577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 14:54:12.959: W/System.err(11577):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 14:54:12.961: W/System.err(11577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-12 14:54:12.963: W/System.err(11577):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-12 14:54:12.965: W/System.err(11577):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why occur exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException`? (I testing on android phone 4.0)

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.  That exception is caused by something else.

Comment: Post your full stacktrace.

Comment: Post the code of your onclick listener.

Comment: my code of onclick listener only call to this function, it had occur exception.

Answer (score 0):

May be this [link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html) can help you. The exception shows that you are doing something in wrong state. Try to release camera before Media Recorder starts..

Comment: If release camera before Media Recorder starts, camera is null , is it not error?